# How to keep only common row names between 4 data frames in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have 4 data frames of genes, each data frame has gene names as row and about 20 columns of sample data. Thus each matrix has that amount of rows (genes):

- A: 10,000 genes
- B: 15,000 genes
- C: 35,000 genes
- D: 12,000 genes

Here is what I tried, it didn't select the complete list of 9,000 common row (Genes)

```
Data_A = read.csv("matrix_A.csv");
Data_B = read.csv("matrix_B.csv");
Data_C = read.csv("matrix_C.csv");
Data_D = read.csv("matrix_D.csv");

Expr_A = as.data.frame(t(Data_A[, -c(1:8)]))
Expr_B = as.data.frame(t(Data_B[, -c(1:8)]))
Expr_C = as.data.frame(t(Data_C[, -c(1:8)]))
Expr_D = as.data.frame(t(Data_D[, -c(1:8)]))

commonGenes1 = intersect (rownames(Data_A),rownames(Data_D))
commonGenes2 = intersect (rownames(Data_B),rownames(Data_D))
commonGenes3 = intersect (rownames(Data_C),rownames(Data_D))

Data_A = Data_A[commonGenes1,]
Data_B = Data_B[commonGenes2,]
Data_C = Data_C[commonGenes3,]
```

They all have 9,000 genes in common, though the data are so big I can't do this in Excel. I'm using R to treat the data, is there a way to select the common genes between the 4 data frames in R?

An example of the 4 matrices is here:
http://www.filedropper.com/matrixexample

Comment: Please givev a reproducible example

Comment: @DatamineR Sure, I just edited the post with the portion that I tried and didn't work..

Comment: It's not really reproducible as you don't supply the data...

Comment: @DatamineR    I can't send you 50,000 rows of data through stackoverflow.. picture that each matrix have on column 1 names, column 2 to column x are just numbers.. and we want to have the common list of names between the 4 matrices. Thanks!

Comment: What DatamineR means is that any user should be able to run the code you provided so that they can help you faster.  Unless you want to provide links to the "matrix_A.csv", "matrix_B.csv"  etc. files (not recommended), you should be able to construct sample data from the code. `dput` is recommended for samples that aren't too large.  Otherwise, come up with a function that emulates the features of the data that are necessary for the problem.

Comment: @user1362215 I uploaded an excel spreadsheet representing the 4 matrices and the virtual selection of common genes. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's actually put things in a list (as your title suggests), it's good practice.

```
list_of_data = list(Data_A, Data_B, Data_C, Data_D)
## for demo purposes, you can use
# list_of_data = list(mtcars[1:6, ], mtcars[4:9, ])

# this will get the intersection of the row.names for everything in the list
common_names = Reduce(intersect, lapply(list_of_data, row.names))

list_of_data = lapply(list_of_data, function(x) { x[row.names(x) %in% common_names,] })
```

Thanks to @eipi10 for a better way to filter rows for each data frame in a list.  Check out the revision history for a lame for loop.

Comment: Gregor, for the last step, what about `lapply(list_of_data, function(x) {
  x[row.names(x) %in% common_names,]
})`

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to see the length of the intersect list_of_data ? Also, can I output the result of the intersect into a file?

Comment: Sure. The intersect names are stored in `common_names`, so you can use `length(common_names)` to see how many there are and you can write out the list with `write.csv(common_names, file = "rows in common.csv")`.

Comment: To check the number of rows in the resulting data frames, `lapply(list_of_data, nrow)`.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
# Create some fake data:
set.seed(123)
m1 <- cbind(sample(1:5), round(rnorm(5),2))
m2 <- cbind(sample(1:5), round(rnorm(5),2))
m3 <- cbind(sample(1:5), round(rnorm(5),2))
m4 <- cbind(sample(1:5), round(rnorm(5),2))
rownames(m1) <- LETTERS[sample(1:10, 5)]
rownames(m2) <- LETTERS[sample(1:10, 5)]
rownames(m3) <- LETTERS[sample(1:10, 5)]
rownames(m4) <- LETTERS[sample(1:10, 5)]


ind <- sapply(list(m1,m2,m3), function(x) intersect(rownames(x), rownames(m4)))
mapply(function(x, y) x[rownames(x) %in% y,], x = list(m1,m2,m3), y = ind)
[[1]]
  [,1]  [,2]
A    4  1.24
D    5 -0.11
E    1  0.18

[[2]]
  [,1]  [,2]
E    5  1.22
C    2 -0.56

[[3]]
  [,1]  [,2]
A    2 -0.22
C    1 -0.33
```